# GET request through a window click with paramters

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML. I have got an URL in the following format:

dosomething?param1=abc&param2-xyz

This URL is guaranteed to be valid.

How I have got an HTML page with a button on that. What I want to do is to send a GET request to the URL by clicking the button.

I have tried this:

```
<form method="GET" action="dosomething?param1=abc&param2-xyz">
    <button>DO Something</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that the parameters are missing on the server side.

What is the proper way to do this? I cannot make an Ajax call on this as it will be a file downloading action and people told me that it won't work with Ajax.

Javascript solution is OK for me.

Please help.

Comment: what server side language are u using. javascript is not a server side language

Comment: where do you handle dosomething on server.it should be like dosomething.php?param1=abc&param2-xyz

Comment: first ensure that the url you got is responding as it should, you can easily do that with a web browser

Comment: The server side is fine. We use Java on the server side. What I mean is that I can use Javascript on the client side to send the GET request through a button.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need Javascript for this as you can simply form your request like

```
<form method="GET" action="dosomething">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="abc">
    <input type="hidden" name="param2-xyz" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="DO Something">
</form>
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Of course you could also use Javascript, you might want to look into using JQuery with http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

see also [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Furthermore, out of interest, what did "people" tell you about "Ajax won't work"?

Comment: From "This URL is guaranteed to be valid." i figured the server side is covered, but of course you need some script to respond to your GET request

Answer (score 0):

The GET paramaters are passed by the input tag. This is a proper way :

```
<form method="GET" action="dosomething.php">
    <input type="text" name="customparam" />
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="value2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When you will click on the submit button, you will be on dosomething.php?customparam=whatiwrote&param1=value1&param2=value2

On your page "dosomething.php", you can access these params with that :

```
<?php
    $customparam = $_GET['customparam'];
    $param1= $_GET['param1'];
    $param2= $_GET['param2'];

    echo "The value of param1 is : ".$param1;
?>
```

If the params don't move, you can also put them in a link directly with :

```
<a href="dosomething.php?param1=value1&param2=value2" >My link </a>
```